# Do operations on the ~/.bash_history file when closing the terminal

Tags: bash, command-history

I want to add another operation to the closing of the terminal in addition to the ones that are already done by default on the `~/.bash_history` file, and they are:

```
tac ~/.bash_history | awk '!x[$0]++' | tac > /tmp/.bash_history
cat /tmp/.bash_history > ~/.bash_history
rm -f /tmp/.bash_history
```

This removes all duplicate values from the "~/.bash_history" file while preserving the last one.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you consider putting above into the `~/.bash_logout` file?

Comment: `.bash_logout` is only for login shells